# Comparison for BigInteger not working

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm not getting the output that I'm expecting. This is for a primality test. I'm not really sure what's wrong. Either my loop isn't working correctly, or this isn't.

n is a BigInteger. It's a random generated by user inputted length.

```
public static boolean isPrime(BigInteger n) {

    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");

    System.out.println(n + " Mod 2 " + n.mod(two));

    if (n.compareTo(one) == 0 || n.compareTo(one) < 0) {
        //System.out.println("HIT1");
        return false;
    } else if (n.compareTo(three) == 0 || n.compareTo(three) < 0) {
        //System.out.println("HIT2");
        return false;
    } else if ((n.mod(two)).compareTo(zero) == 0 || (n.mod(three)).compareTo(zero) == 0) {
        //System.out.println("HIT3");
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Heres n : " + n);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's my loop. I know for sure that my number generator works though.

```
do {
    num1 = generateNumber(p);
} while (isPrime(generateNumber(p)) == false);

do {
    num2 = generateNumber(q);
} while (isPrime(generateNumber(q)) == false);
```

Comment: What is `n` first? Moreover, I don't see any loop in here!

Comment: What input are you giving, what output are you getting and **how** is that output not matching your ***expectations***?

Comment: n is a BigInteger. It's a random generated by user inputted length.

Comment: I keep getting even numbers. Sometimes I even get one. Which it shouldn't be outputting given the first IF statement.

Comment: For **what** `n`? Your printing `n` at the top. And how are you getting `n`? Is it a `static` field, or are you passing it to the method?

Comment: `else if (n.compareTo(three) == 0 || n.compareTo(three) == -1)` --> This should return true because 2 and 3 are prime

Comment: Edited with more code. It's being passed into the method.

Comment: The `n.compareTo(one) == 0 || n.compareTo(one) < 0` pattern can be simplified and optimized to `n.compareTo(one) <= 0`.

Comment: @Nayuki whoops, thanks that's supposed to be true. I set that as false for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized what the issue was. I'm generating two different numbers in the loop and inside the loop. I was also incorrectly assigning the BigInteger incorrectly in the loop. I should be doing
    num1 = new BigInteger(generateNumber(p).toString());

Answer (score 1):

Don't test if the result of `compareTo()` equals -1. When you want to mean `a < b`, you should write `a.compareTo(b) < 0`. Always compare with 0, not any other constant.

Comment: Makes sense, tried it, but I'm still getting one sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

First, test if the number is `2` (if it is, then it is prime). Next, test if the number is divisible by `2` (if it is, then it is not prime). Next, iterate from `3` to the square root of the number in increments of `2` testing for divisibility with the original number (if it is, then it is not prime). Otherwise, the number is prime. Something like,

```
public static boolean isPrime(BigInteger n) {
    final BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    if (n.equals(two)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (BigInteger i = two.add(BigInteger.ONE); i.multiply(i).compareTo(n) < 1;
                i = i.add(two)) {
        if (n.mod(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```